# Can't understand the のための場所以上にpart

Tags: grammar

I've been reading some japanese and encountered this sentence:

> アメリカでは、犯罪人を収容する刑務所**のための場所以上に**犯罪人がいる**のでいつも**刑務所は定員オーバーの状態である

I'm having trouble with the 「のための場所以上に」 and 「のでいつも」 parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `のため` means "purpose", so `刑務所のための場所` means "places [than can be used] for the purpose of prisons", so places that can be used as prison; `以上` means "more than", so, `刑務所のための場所以上に犯罪人がいる` means "there are more criminals than places that can be used as prisons".

`のでいつも` is made of `ので`, "because, since"; and `いつも`, "always", so `刑務所のための場所以上に犯罪人がいるので` means "since there are more criminals than places that can be used as prisons", and `いつも` belongs to the next part: `いつも刑務所`, "prisons are always".

The full translation should be something like "In America, since there are more criminals than places that can be used as prisons to accomodate them, prisons are always in a condition of overcapacity".